# Kotlin gradle script setup

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to compile simple Kotlin Gradle script.
I've created a project in Idea with build.gradle.kts with following contents:

```
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

tasks {
    register("runScript", Copy::class) {
        from("data")
        into("out")
    }
}
```

It was inspired by copy sample inside gradle/kotlin-dsl repository and it's not compiling either from IDE or gradlew in terminal.
It gives me these errors:

```
e: /Users/dalexiv/Workspace/script-zipper/build.gradle.kts:5:5: Unresolved reference: register
e: /Users/dalexiv/Workspace/script-zipper/build.gradle.kts:5:27: Unresolved reference: Copy
e: /Users/dalexiv/Workspace/script-zipper/build.gradle.kts:6:9: Unresolved reference: from
e: /Users/dalexiv/Workspace/script-zipper/build.gradle.kts:7:9: Unresolved reference: into
```

Maybe I missing some kind of plugin to include? How do I do that?

Comment: Just guessing - are you using _IntelliJ IDEA_ as IDE?

Answer (score 0):

```
tasks.register("runScript", Copy::class.java) {
    from("data")
    into("out")
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestiong and output is still the same. 4 unresolved references :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using *Gradle* with version lower than **4.10**.

In case of `gradlew`, you can check the file `<project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` for the value of `distributionUrl` and change it to version `4.10+`, e.g.:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Speaking the IDE, I guess that you are using *IntelliJ IDEA* (or some sibling). The problem is that the current version of *IDEA* (`2018.2.3`) generates - for *Gradle Kotlin DSL* project - *Gradle* wrapper with version `4.8`, which causes your problem. If your *IntelliJ* project uses *Gradle* wrapper, then the solution is the same as the one above.

Another solution could be that you set *local gradle distribution* with version `4.10+`.

[image]